# Upvoted rather than flagged a comment; can it be undone?

Tags: support, comment, flagging

I was trying to flag a comment [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36782/graphing-inequalities/36783#36783), and messed up and upvoted it instead. I immediately tried to cancel the upvote to discover, somewhat to my surprise, that comment upvotes cannot be undone even immediately. Any way of getting rid of that upvote?

*Added.* I've now [posted a feature-request in meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89862/moving-the-flag-for-comments-to-the-right) requesting that the flag be moved to the right. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, unfortunately.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Well, could the comment be edited or deleted? I'm sure you can figure out which one it is. The (implicit) question itself is sort of okay, though of course I would not have upvoted it.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thanks.

Comment: Here's the related (status-declined) request on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment

Comment: I was thinking of perhaps asking that the "flag" link be placed on the right (same location as you would find the "delete" tag for your own comment). That would prevent this kind of mistake, and would have some symmetry (with up-vote on the left, and flag/delete on the right). I may yet post a request for that on meta.stackoverflow tomorrow.

Comment: @Arturo: that would be a good UI improvement, I think, especially in view of Akhil's earlier observation that if a moderator tries to flag a comment, the comment will be deleted immediately. So there's some advantage to having the two together in the same place also for moderators.

Comment: On that MSO question (which is the second highest voted status-declined question on MSO), there's the amusing/ironic fact that Jeff wrote a blog post complaining about exactly this point: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to undo comment votes at this time.

Answer (score 5):

Unupvoting comments is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Here's the meta.SO thread already linked in the comments, where you can read more:

[Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)