# Why cannot I unlike a comment I liked by mistake?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upvoted rather than flagged a comment; can it be undone?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/upvoted-rather-than-flagged-a-comment-can-it-be-undone)

Unlike actual answers why is this option not enabled?

Comment: Related question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/upvoted-rather-than-flagged-a-comment-can-it-be-undone

Comment: Oh sorry, it did not show up when I typed it. Please feel free to merge or delete this.